# Why can't this very simple in_array works?

Tags: php

```
$country='ID';
echo '$country:' . $country;
echo "\n arCountry: ";
print_r ($arCountry);
echo "\n" . 'in_array($country,$arCountry): ';
echo in_array($country,$arCountry);
```

Result:

```
$country:ID
 arCountry: Array
(
    [0] => UK
    [1] => 
US
    [2] => 
ID
)

in_array($country,$arCountry):
```

clearly `$arCountry` contains ID

Yet     `in_array($country,$arCountry)`:  is just empty

Comment: Can we see the definition of arCountry?

Comment: Looks to me like `$arCountry[2]` contains something like `"\nID"` which is certainly not `"ID"`

Comment: @l'L'l I wouldn't try guessing at the whitespace character(s) in play here

Comment: @l'L'l it might still. For all we know, the entry is `"   \r\nID      "`

Comment: That is correct. The problem is that there is ]

Comment: Phil, would you please turn your comment into the answer because that's actually what was the problem and that's something all future people with the same problem should look at whitespace around characters when things like this happen.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not keen on cleaning up the data in `$arCountry`, you could try mapping it to something more useful

```
in_array($country, array_map('trim', $arCountry))
```